# JSON response from API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, jsonp

I am trying to pull in weather data in JSON form using an API. It is successfully returning data from the API, however when trying to access the properties of the object I get the following:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I know the response is coming back because I can see it returns this

```
{"coord":{"lon":122,"lat":45},"sys":{"message":0.0024,"country":"CN","sunrise":1460581662,"sunset":1460630193},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":280.37,"temp_min":280.37,"temp_max":280.37,"pressure":1004.49,"sea_level":1024.21,"grnd_level":1004.49,"humidity":77},"wind":{"speed":6.9,"deg":182.004},"clouds":{"all":92},"rain":{"3h":1.92},"dt":1460668593,"id":2034323,"name":"Tuquan","cod":200}
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
function displayWeatherAndLocation() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/",
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        lat: "45",
        lon: "122",
        APPID: "b8d8272fd3bdb1f099b1288ff750d5e2"
    }
})
.done(test)
.fail();
}

function test(response) {
   console.log(response.main.temp);
}
```

Comment: That response is JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: Ok so, what is the proper way to deal with the information I am returning from this API? I thought you had to use jsonp when making an external ajax request? I am giving it a function to return the data to, which is what I thought was going on with jsonp?

Comment: You can only do that if the service supports it. If they don't do JSONP, and they don't support CORS, you need to make the request from a script on your server.

Comment: @Barmar that's right, but it appears they do support CORS, because he says he is getting the JSON back (and he's probably using the app ID for CORS to be effective).

Comment: @blex The data always comes back, CORS is implemented by the browser, not the server. If the response doesn't contain the appropriate headers, the browser discards the response and reports an error. But when you use JSONP, it doesn't use XMLHttpRequest, it creates a `<script>` tag that points to the remote URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just request the data normally. Don't use jsonp. jQuery will handle the conversion for you.

```js
function displayWeatherAndLocation() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/",
    data: {
        lat: "45",
        lon: "122",
        APPID: "b8d8272fd3bdb1f099b1288ff750d5e2"
    }
  })
  .done(test)
  .fail();
}

function test(weatherData) {
   document.querySelector('pre').innerText = weatherData.main.temp;
}

$('button').click(displayWeatherAndLocation);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me</button><br />
<pre></pre>
```